# What are some alternatives to Griffiths Harris 'Principles of algebraic geometry" chapters 0 and 1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I liked using Rick Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces chapters I to VIII as an alternative to Griffiths' Introduction to Algebraic Curves. I notice they overlap in most topics.

I notice Rick Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces IX onwards overlaps with Griffiths Harris "Principles of algebraic geometry" chapters 0 and 1, but not really for most topics.

What are some alternatives to Griffiths Harris "Principles of algebraic geometry" chapters 0 and 1 that preferably are like Rick Miranda's Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces chapters I to VIII as an alternative to Griffiths' Introduction to Algebraic Curves?

Here's a screenshot of the table of contents for Griffiths Harris "Principles of algebraic geometry" chapters 0 and 1

> [image]

P.S. Not sure if this relevant, but: I was told in a comment to one of my deleted questions that Griffiths' Introduction to Algebraic Curves is a prerequisite to griffiths harris principles of algebraic geometry.

---

Edit: Maybe related:

[What to study after Miranda's "Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858971/what-to-study-after-mirandas-algebraic-curves-and-riemann-surfaces)

[What do I need to read Philip Griffths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706607/what-do-i-need-to-read-philip-griffths)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think pretty much everything you need is in Huybrechts' book titled *Complex Geometry.* This has the benefit of having many exercises and being written for someone new to the subject, whereas I think that Griffiths and Harris assumes that you already have had exposure to the materials in chapter $0$.

The book is available through Springer.

Comment: well i did start with Huybrechts' Complex Geometry before even miranda (see my previous questions on complexification eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520787/f-is-the-complexification-of-a-map-if-f-commutes-with-almost-complex-structu) but got stuck on complexification. good to know i can use huybrechts as an alternative. thanks!

Comment: Did huybrecht have a self contained chapter on Hodge theory?

Comment: Huybrechts does discuss Hodge theory in some level of detail. Like most introductory books on the subject, he doesn't get too far into the analytic aspect of the subject.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon if you've read most of Miranda since you last looked at Huybrechts, you will probably find it much easier going now that you have studied much of the $1$-dimensional theory. Although I don't think he covers Grassmannians, for which you might want to just bite the bullet and read Griffiths-Harris (or some of Harris' more recent expositions, such as in *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course* or *3264 and All That* (the latter joint with Eisenbud).

Comment: Alekos Robotis , i think you have to tag like this @ArcticChar. thanks Alekos Robotis and ArcticChar!